How would I create the texture and bumpy moss covered trees in this image?
I really like the look of the trees and hills in the image below. I'm assuming they used some kind of procedural generation or particle system to achieve the bumpy/mossy balls on the trees and hills but I can't seem to replicate it. Does anyone have any ideas? I know I could probably manually do it but that will take a lot of work.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hello, I'm not sure it's a question of lighting, maybe you want to create this fog effect? There are at least 2 methods: Use volumetrics (create a cube that encompass your scene and give it a Principled Volume node) or create mist through the Compositor, maybe tell in what solution are you more interested?

Please do not roll back my change. See comments by the moderator you must have a descriptive title and your title is not descriptive enough. Please read the link he shared https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this If you meant something else than what I put in your title then please describe it properly in the title.

That's fine but your edit completely missed what I was asking and changed the question completely that is why I rolled it back. If you're going to update it at least keep the same question.

@user41829 It was impossible to know what you were asking for so I tried to guess it as lighting since you did not try to be more specific but just rolled it back to be unclear again. But thank you for finally updating it for clarity.

If you are talking about the mist, there are several solutions:
You could create a cube that contains your scene and give it a Principled Volume node, this will be the most accurate solution, in particular for light effects:

A lighter solution would be to use the Compositor. First thing activate the Mist option in the View Layer panel:

Then in the Compositor plug the Mist output of the Render Layers node into a ColorRamp that you plug into a Mix Color in Add mode:

Last solution, even lighter, create a series of planes and give them a half trnasparent noise texture:

For solution #2 and #3 you can create fake light rays with a Layer Weight node as factor between an Emission and a Transparent node:


Great overview over the different techniques! One thing might be confusing, when talking about enabling the Mist pass, your arrow is pointing on the depth pass Z... which is not necessary to be enabled for the mist but can be used for a similar effect as well, but you do not explain that method. Although I would not either, for compositing mist the Z pass is not so great as it needs to be normalized and/or divided and also anti-aliased, which is "ready to use" in the Mist pass. Overall I think the Mist pass offers more tangible control with distances you can enter for start and end.

@Gordon Brinkmann Hello Gordon, I'm not sure to understand, could you please write your own answer and I'll edit mine to correct?

There is nothing to understand really... after your sentence "First thing activate the Mist option in the View Layer panel" you show a screenshot where your green arrow is pointing on the Z pass, not the Mist pass (but they are both enabled), I just thought it might confuse beginners to either think you meant the wrong pass or the Z pass has to enabled as well, which is not. Everything's fine with your answer, that was just for clarification which pass to use.

Oops of course sorry

Really appreciate this in depth overview. It was really interesting to learn about! Unfortunately a mod completely changed my question and this wasn't what I was asking about but I really appreciate it and I'm sure someone will find it useful!

@user41829 completely changed it? it was unclear from the get go. it was impossible to know what you were asking for.
